# Java program to send huge number of mails unsequentially

Tags: java, mysql, email, smtp

I am trying to develop a java program that will read from a table which has entries such
 as id, fromemailaddress, to email address, subject and body and send emails over the
SMTP server .  Also for speed I want that emails should not be sent sequentially.
For example if I have 1 million mails to be sent , they should not be sent sequentially. 
Also it should scale i.e.If the fastest we can send emails from one server is 300 mails per
 second I should also be able to run the same program on other server and it should 
also be able to send 300 mails per second.

How should I start with this in Java . The  Javamail library is there but how to do 
something better than sequentially in sending the mails using SMTP .

Comment: If you're developing in java, why are you tagging this question php?

Comment: Sorry @MarkBaker I have edited it .Actually I thought I might insert into the table using PHP and MySQL .

Answer (score 0):

Get the records from table and group it according to category then create `threads` for those category and send mails. This can be one approach.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear about it as to how will I group them according to category and then create threads correspondingly .